# Create flag column set from original columns, '1' when missing values

Tags: python, python-3.x

Apologies if this is a simple issue, I am trying to tech myself python.  I have a panda dataframe that has a large number of columns with missing values. I am going to impute those values for the modeling part, but I also want to see if the fact that they are missing is important.

To do this I am trying to create a second set of binary columns that are 1 when the observation in the column is null, 0 else.  My code is as follows:

```
test=train_17
col_names=test.columns.tolist()
for col in col_names:
    for row in test[col]:
        if test[col][row].isnull():
            test[col+"_missing"] = 1
        else:
            test[col+"_missing"] = 0
```

When I attempt to do this I get a kKeyError: 14297519. In the log I also see this:

```
tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
```

Does anybody have any thoughts or suggestions about what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Note that there is no need to convert `test.columns` to a list. You can simply iterate over `test.columns`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function `isnull` works on the whole pandas.Dataframe or pandas.Series, so you can assign a new column to `test[col].isnull()`.

```
for col in test.columns:
    test[col+"_missing"] = test[col].isnull()
```